# Intro text for teaching basic computing math to first year math students

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, python

I'm looking for a text to teach a "computational math" course next year.

I have to cover mathematical aspects of basic number theory (primes, modular arithmetic), sorting, search, trees, and graph algorithms with some foray in complexity count and average compute times.

The softest part of Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest (a great book but too spooky for my students) with a mathematical emphasis but also with a practical part (possibly using Python).

I want an accessible text for mathematicians (not computer scientists) interested in turning math into code. In a sense, I want the dual of Don Knuth's Concrete Mathematics.